# using AppService in winrt/c++

Tags: c++, uwp, c++-winrt

I am trying to use an AppService in winrt/c++, following the github sample in C++/Cx. I always get the "AppUnavailable" result. I have confirmed I connect to the correct service name and have the correct family package name.

My appxmanifest:

```
  <Extensions>
    <uap:Extension Category="windows.appService" EntryPoint="BlankApp5.Inventory">
      <uap3:AppService Name="com.microsoft.inventory" uap4:SupportsMultipleInstances="true"/>
    </uap:Extension>
  </Extensions>
```

My provider header file (in Mainpage.h):

```
namespace winrt::BlankApp5::implementation
{
class Inventory : public InventoryT<Inventory> {
public:
    virtual void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance);

private:
    BackgroundTaskDeferral mDef;
    AppServiceConnection appServiceConnection;
};
```

My MainPage.idl file:

```
[default_interface]
runtimeclass Inventory : Windows.ApplicationModel.Background.IBackgroundTask
{
    void Run(Windows.ApplicationModel.Background.IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance);
}
```

During IDL generation I get the following warning:

```
[msg]A member name has been qualified with an interface name because name collisions occurred across interface members on a runtime class. [context]"Run" has been renamed as "BlankApp5.IInventory.Run" on runtime class "BlankApp5.Inventory"
```

I am a bit worried that the Inventory::Run gets stripped by the linker, as it is not used internally in the serviceprovider, but I have no other idea why it doesnt work. The provider and client are in two different solutions and have no references between each other, but I assume this is not needed. The service prodiver has been deployed, but not launched. Launching makes no difference.

Comment: Have you checked this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/how-to-create-and-consume-an-app-service#debug-the-app-service)?

Comment: Yes i followed that one

Answer (score 0):

You needn't declare the `void Run(Windows.ApplicationModel.Background.IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance);` in your idl file, because you implement `IBackgroundTask` and a `void Run` is declared implicitly.